Subscriptions public on postgraphile
Currently, I have a project that has a middleware where it checks that each subscription has in the request the JWT:
     if (config.graphileConfig?.subscriptions === true) {
        // Subscriptions have been activated, so we need to verify JWT on those connections as well
        config.graphileConfig.websocketMiddlewares = [checkJwt];
      }

Based on a new need I must make a whitelist type to allow a subscription to be consumed in a public way but when I try to intercept the request I get it as an HTTP request and not as a WS connection, is there any way to make this filter efficient?
      if (config.graphileConfig?.subscriptions === true) {
        // Subscriptions have been activated, so we need to verify JWT on those connections as well
        config.graphileConfig.websocketMiddlewares = [checkJwt.unless(PublicAccessPlugin)];
      }

      export const PublicAccessPlugin = (req: express.Request) => {
       // req -> http request
      return false;
      };

A computer solution with express
